# How Can I Find the Incorrect Bits of a UDP Packet Using CRC32 Checksums?

Tags: udp, checksum, packet, crc32, integrity

I have a server that receives UDP packets. I want to verify the integrity of the packet.

What I am confused about is that I am told the packets contain a "variable number of checksums". I don't quite understand what this means. The sender sends the number of checksums to be performed in the packet and I see how to extract it, however, I don't know how to use it.

The packets also contain a packet sequence number that represents the total number of checksums processed (AKA the iteration the first checksum in its body is on).

I'm not sure what exactly this means, but I need to use it to figure out the checksum I was sent as well as the one I *expected* to receive.

In the past, I have been exposed to the idea of checksums. For example, say I am sent this data

```
100100001
```

And this key

```
1101
```

Then I would normally do a CRC check like so

```
     _______________
1101 ) 100100001
     + 1101,,,,,
       ----,,,,,
       01000,,,,
      + 1101,,,,
        ----,,,,
        01010,,,
       + 1101,,,
         ----,,,
         01110,,
        + 1101,,
          ----,,
          001101
          + 1101
            ----
               0 <-- Remainder of 0, no error found!
```

Where a remainder of 0 means that there is (most likely) no problem with the data.

In my case, I need to calculate the CRC32 I expect and the one I actually received. There could possibly be a library that could help me do this, which would be very helpful.

Hopefully I've provided enough details and provided a clear explanation. If anything needs to be clarified, please let me now.

Answer (score 1):

No, you have not provided enough information. You need to provide or link to what exactly is the format of these packages and what they use for their integrity check. There is no "the" CRC-32. There are many possible CRC-32's. There is no one format for what you can send in UDP packets.

The answer to your title question is: you *can't* find the incorrect bits. At least not if a CRC is being used. A CRC is not an error-correcting code. It is an error-*detecting* code. The best you can do is discover that there is at least one error, but not which bits are in error.

The basic answer to what I think you're asking in the text of the question is: you calculate the integrity check (whatever it is) on the message, and compare that to the integrity check that was sent with the message.

Depending on which CRC-32 is being used, there are likely many libraries to calculate it. One commonly used CRC-32 is calculated by the [zlib library](https://zlib.net/), which likely already installed on your machine. There is [code out there](https://github.com/madler/crcany) that will generate code for any given CRC.

A correction: the thing you are calling the "key" is not a key. It is the CRC polynomial.

Comment: I see, thank you for this valuable information. What exactly is the XOR key then? In the packet, it is called a "repeating XOR key". Also, I have another question - you say to "calculate the integrity check on the message, and compare that to the integrity check that was sent with the message". Just to be clear, I should calculate my integrity check on the message without the one that was sent, right? If it helps, I am given a repeating XOR key, the number of checksums I need to do, and a variable number of bytes representing repeating key XOR'd cyclic checksum CRC32 DWORDS.

Comment: You need to provide a link to what you are paraphrasing and quoting in your comment. I can't make heads or tails out of what you're writing, but I expect that the documentation you are reading will make sense to me.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm very new to this. I really do appreciate your help. Here is a link to what I am working on, hopefully this can clear things up. https://imgur.com/a/1QNYnLt

Comment: It's a coding assessment. All I really want to to have my confusion cleared up. I've been researching and can't find anything about "multiple checksums". And after you explained that the XOR key isn't the same as the generator polynomial, I'm a bit more lost than I thought. I didn't learn this stuff in college, but it's extremely interesting and I want to perform well on the assessment.

Comment: I've been researching for hours, but I'm not really finding what I need. If you could help steer me in the right direction, that would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Can't help. The snippet you provided an image of makes no sense in isolation.

Comment: Hm, interesting (and quite frustrating, I have spent hours trying to figure this out). I suppose I can ask them for clarification. Are there any resources you could possibly point me to that talks about this idea of "multiple checksums" in general? Or where I can learn the purpose of an XOR key? I am struggling to find anything that even remotely helps.

Comment: Ok... Is doing multiple checksums a thing at all...? I'm just trying to research it, but I don't want to waste any more of my time looking for something that doesn't exist.